# Pests on a Kiyomi Tangor orange tree

Tags: fruit-trees, insects, orange

A few months ago we purchased a Kiyomi Tangor orange tree from a local, quality nursery. It is planted in a large pot indoors with lots of light. The tree has been doing well with lots of new growth.

Today we realized that the older growth seems to be infested with a big of some sort.

See images and let me know if you have any advice for how to treat it.
[image: stem with bugs]
[image: leaf with bugs]
[image: full view of tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is citrus scale, common on citrus and hard to really get rid of.  More details are [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/59587/499).

I recommend removing every leaf on the plant then rubbing the stems with soap and water at five day intervals. You can use a rag or paper towel.  Repeat at least three times and don't be afraid to do more applications

This is effective because:

- you are reducing the surface to cover by removing the leaves
- by using a rag or paper towel you are crushing the scale and ensuring complete coverage
- by repeating the soap and water at least three time you are getting the ones you didn't get the first time and the eggs that have hatched

Reduce water after removing the leaves until new ones grow.  No fertilizer until it is clean.

Comment: So sad. Guess this plant is going back to the nursery.